# Trim spaces in headers when use @CsvBindByName annotation

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I use opencsv

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I have this class for mapping:

```
public class LineDto {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "First name", required = true)
    private String firstName;

    //getters setters

}
```

I need to prevent some user mistakes and if user uplods CSV file where header is `" First name "` it should be OK. For now, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Header is missing required fields [FIRST NAME, ...]. The list of headers encountered is [ First name ,...].
```

How can I trim headers or improve mapping to support those spaces?

Comment: Are the colums orderded? if yes you can use the position binding

Comment: @Jens I use CsvBindByName because I need binding by name

Comment: @PavelPetrashov did you found a solution ? I have the same issue as you